# How to add different product to an ad from product sets in facebook marketing?

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I have completely read out the documentation of dynamic facebook marketing.Also successfully created an ad based on custom audience and pixel events.But the problem is that every time i am creating an ad it shows same product in ad templates.

Here is the code for setting up the Product set

```
    product_set = ProductSet(None, <CATALOG ID>) # <CATALOG ID>
    product_set[ProductSet.Field.name] = 'Product Set'
    product_set[ProductSet.Field.filter] = {
        'product_type': {
            'i_contains': 'example product type',
        },
    }
    product_set.remote_create()
    product_set_id =  product_set[ProductSet.Field.id]
```

And Code for creating AD after setting campaign and adset :

```
    adset = AdSet(parent_id='<ACCOUNT_ID>')
    adset[AdSet.Field.name] = 'Product Adset'
    adset[AdSet.Field.bid_amount] = 9100
    adset[AdSet.Field.billing_event] = AdSet.BillingEvent.link_clicks
    adset[AdSet.Field.optimization_goal] = AdSet.OptimizationGoal.link_clicks
    adset[AdSet.Field.daily_budget] = 45500
    adset[AdSet.Field.campaign_id] = campaign_id
    adset[AdSet.Field.targeting] = {
        Targeting.Field.publisher_platforms: ['facebook', 'audience_network'],
        Targeting.Field.device_platforms: ['desktop','mobile'],
        Targeting.Field.geo_locations: {
            Targeting.Field.countries: ['IN'],
        },
        Targeting.Field.product_audience_specs: [
            {
                'product_set_id': product_set_id,
                'inclusions': [
                    {
                        'retention_seconds': 2592000,
                        'rule': {
                            'event': {
                                'eq': 'ViewContent',
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
                'exclusions': [
                    {
                        'retention_seconds': 259200,
                        'rule': {
                            'event': {
                                'eq': 'Purchase',
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
        Targeting.Field.excluded_product_audience_specs: [
            {
                'product_set_id': product_set_id,
                'inclusions': [
                    {
                        'retention_seconds': 259200,
                        'rule': {
                            'event': {
                                'eq': 'ViewContent',
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
    adset[AdSet.Field.promoted_object] = {
        'product_set_id': product_set_id,
    }

    adset.remote_create()
    adset_id = adset[AdSet.Field.id]
```

Can you guys help me out for the creating dynamic products from product set ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your product catalog have items with product_type containing 'example product type'? you can make a api call to verify how many products are under that product set by `/<PRODUCT_SET_ID>?fields=product_count,products`

when the ads start running, it'll automatically render the relevant products from the product set automatically.

for the creative preview, you can specify specific product items to render in the preview: e.g. `product_item_ids=["catalog:1000005:MTIzNDU2"]`

more details about creative preview of Dynamic Ads: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/ads-management/v2.9